# Can't return namespace from SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I am creating a new xml document from scratch using a google defined format and SimpleXML. I'm having problems getting it to return namespaced tags. To test, I wrote this:

```
<?php

  $output_xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" ?> <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0"><channel></channel></rss>');

  var_dump($output_xml->getNameSpaces(TRUE));
```

which returns this:

```
array(0) {
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm running PHP version 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't used any of the namespaces defined. if you add your "g" namespace to "channel" then you will get http://base.google.com/ns/1.0

```
$output_xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" ?> <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0"><g:channel></g:channel></rss>');

var_dump($output_xml->getNameSpaces(TRUE));
```

Comment: Edited for clarity (pending peer review): the namespaces are *defined*, just not *used* anywhere.